# Get First and Last element of a Collection at the same time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mvvmcross

I'm currently working on a cross platform Project.

I'm facing the problem when trying to map the model between WebDataLayer.Models and Shared.Models.

```
namespace WebDataLayer.Models
{
    public class Factory
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Serie { get; set; }

        public Guid? AreaId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<FactoryHotline> FactoryHotlines { get; set; }
}

public class FactoryHotline
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid FactoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(256)]
        public string Caption { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(256)]
        public string Hotline { get; set; }
    }
```

This is model in Shared:

```
namespace Shared.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Factory
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "areaId")]
        public Guid AreaId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "serie")]
        public string Serie { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "hotLine1")]
        public FactoryHotline Hotline1 { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "hotLine2")]
        public FactoryHotline Hotline2 { get; set; }
    }

public class FactoryHotline
    {
        [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Name = "Id")]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "FactoryId")]
        public Guid FactoryId { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Caption")]
        public string Caption { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Hotline")]
        public string Hotline { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is code in Controller where I try to convert `WebDatalayer.Models.Factory` to `Shared.Models.Factory`:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            var factories = _factoryService.All().OrderBy(p => p.Name);
            List<Shared.Models.Factory> response = new List<Shared.Models.Factory>();

            response =  factories.Select(k => new Shared.Models.Factory
             {
                 Id = k.Id,
                 Name = k.Name,
                 Serie = k.Serie,
                 Hotline1 = new Shared.Models.FactoryHotline {
                     Id = k.FactoryHotlines.FirstOrDefault().Id,
                     Caption = k.FactoryHotlines.FirstOrDefault().Caption,
                     Hotline = k.FactoryHotlines.FirstOrDefault().Hotline,
                     FactoryId = k.FactoryHotlines.FirstOrDefault().FactoryId
                 },
                 Hotline2 = new Shared.Models.FactoryHotline
                 {
                     Id = k.FactoryHotlines.LastOrDefault().Id,
                     Caption = k.FactoryHotlines.LastOrDefault().Caption,
                     Hotline = k.FactoryHotlines.LastOrDefault().Hotline,
                     FactoryId = k.FactoryHotlines.LastOrDefault().FactoryId
                 },
            }).OrderBy(f => f.Name).ToList();
            return View("Edit", response);
        }
```

But `linq to entities does not recognize the method lastordefault`, cannot use `order descending` because I also get First element at the same time.

Need help!

Answer (score 1):

You look like you want to return all factories ordered by name, and for each factory, return the first and last hotline:

```
var query = factories.Select(f => new Shared.Models.Factory
    {
        Id = f.Id, 
        Name = f.Name,
        Serie = f.Serie,
        Hotline1 = f.FactoryHotLines
            .OrderBy(h => h.Id)
            .Select(h => new Shared.Models.FactoryHotline 
            {
                Id = h.Id,
                Caption = h.Caption,
                Hotline = h.Hotline,
                FactoryId = h.FactoryId
            }).FirstOrDefault(),
        Hotline2 = x.FactoryHotLines
            .OrderByDescending(h => h.Id)
            .Select(h => new Shared.Models.FactoryHotline 
            {
                Id = h.Id,
                Caption = h.Caption,
                Hotline = h.Hotline,
                FactoryId = h.FactoryId
            }).FirstOrDefault(),
     }).OrderBy(f => f.Name)
     .ToList();
```

Key thing here: When using `FirstOrDefault()`, always provide an `OrderBy` clause. Rather than relying on `FirstOrDefault()` to get each individual value, use it with the `OrderBy()` to get the entity then use `Select()` to reduce it down to the desired view model.

The above example assumes you want the order they were added. (ID for identity-based records)  This way we do the `OrderBy()` to get the first hotline, then an `OrderByDescending()` to get the second.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest solution, but you could chain `.Where` like this:

```
.Where((v, i) => { return i == 0 || i == list.Count() -1; })
```

So..

```
factories = factories.Where((v, i) => { return i == 0 || i == factories.Count() -1; })
```